# Can you set up a static IP address

Tags: static-ip-address

Apologies.  I did search for this question/answer, but they were too technical for me so I have to start a new question.

Is it possible to set up my own static IP address without buying this from my internet provider?  I use Sky Broadband.  I googled this and found some sites that give instructions on how to update your internet properties to a single fixed IP but I'm not sure if this applies to me or if I also need something else.  (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/)

Thank you for your help!
Allison

Answer (score 4):

There are two kinds of IP-Adresses you use.

1st: You have your local IP-Address for your local Network. This one can be static, configured like the description in this link.

2nd: You have a public IP-Address you get from your provider. This one will get changed everytime you restart your router or by default one time a day (most likly in the middle of the night). If you want to Host a server and make it public, you need a static IP-Address from your provider. This one you must buy from your internet provider.

I hope this discription helps you a little.

Answer (score 0):

The How-To Geek article is about assigning static IP address on your own home network.

If you want to get an IP address (static or otherwise) in someone else's network, you'll have to arrange it with the owner of that network. Typical providers use a dynamic allocation to spread their pool of addresses among their subscribers, you'll need to ask your provider to give you a static address instead (if that is even a service they offer).

Comment: Thank you.  I'm looking for a public static IP, so looks like I can't just update in my Properties.  :-(